# How to Fix: Error: Segmentation Violation and IncludePath Needs to be Updated from Debugger

Tags: c++, c, include, header-files, root-framework

I am working with ROOT and have ROOT installed in my computer. I am writing my code using Visual Studio. In my code I have the following header files:

```
#include "ROOT/RDataFrame.hxx"
#include "ROOT/RVec.hxx"
#include "ROOT/RDF/RInterface.hxx"
#include "TCanvas.h"
#include "TH1D.h"
#include "TLatex.h"
#include "TLegend.h"
#include "Math/Vector4Dfwd.h"
#include "TStyle.h"
```

My code can't run however and it generates a segmentation violation. When I run the debugger in Visual Studio it indicates that the source files cannot be found and that I need to update my includePath. However, I have already set my compilerPath to /usr/bin/gcc which I in many sites that is how to fix such errors. I also know when I install ROOT these header files should already be installed with it. Does anyone know how I can fix these errors? 
Thanks!

Comment: Is this C or C++? They are not the same. What method are you using to build this project? Makefile? Something else?

Comment: I am writing it in C++ and running it in ROOT. I do not have a method to add all the header files. I am not sure what the best way would be

Comment: It sounds like ROOT is something that interprets C++ code or that compiles it itself? I don't know how that works, so I'll have to defer to someone who knows ROOT.

Comment: Go to the ROOT website and download what you need: https://root.cern.ch/content/release-62000

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah Thank you for the link but which link has all the header files?

Comment: It depends on what compiler and OS you are running, but you didn't say.  I just downloaded one at random (because I am not trying to build it the compiler and OS don't matter) and the header files were under root/include inside the package.  But the file you download does matter because, besides the header files you need for compiling, you also need the libraries for the link step and they have to match your compiler and OS.

Comment: Or you could just clone the github repo.  The headers you are using are at https://github.com/root-project/root/tree/master/graf2d/gpad/inc and https://github.com/root-project/root/tree/master/tree/dataframe/inc

Comment: Does that include the RDataFrames header files, too?

Comment: Even if you download all these headers you won't be able to run anything without having ROOT installed. If you don't have ROOT installed, the missing headers should the least of your worries. If you do have it installed, please let us know how exactly you are trying to run your code.

Comment: No, I do have ROOT installed and I just run it from my Ubuntu terminal and type root -l select.cpp

Comment: In that case chances are you don't need any of the includes. Try that, and if that doesn't work, try to find a way to share you `select.cpp` with us.

Comment: The tutorial I am referencing though has those includes

Comment: Is there a way to send you the code

Comment: I tried your suggestion of commenting out the includes and it still generated a segmentation violation.

Comment: Segmentation violation has nothing to do with missing includes. There must be another reason for it. Which tutorial are you referring to? You can also share the code via the [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com) service or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow any of these tutorials to correctly setup a debugger IDE:

- https://root.cern/blog/code-horsepower-f1
- https://root.cern/blog/debuging-root-scripts-in-eclipse
- https://root.cern/blog/root-on-vscode